# Boss threatens employee with losing their job if they don't cooperate in forcing an ex-employee to drop charges

Tags: united-states, manager, conflict-resolution, sexual-harassment, conflict-of-interest

A friend's manager recently fired a coworker for no apparent reason, even though most people in the office considered the ex-coworker to be hard-working and efficient.

After some time the ex-coworker pressed sexual harassment charges against the manager and the company.

My friend kept in touch with the ex-coworker although they never became close friends.

Knowing that my friend is still in contact with the ex-coworker, the manager had a confidential conversation requesting that my friend tells the ex-coworker of all the bad things that might happen if the ex-coworker does not drop the legal charges. My friend refused to pass the threats over to the ex-coworker. The manager made it clear that if my friend does not cooperate then that can result in job loss.

What might be an optimum strategy in this case apart from or before trying to contact people higher up in the management or the HR department?

Comment: What jurisdiction are you in?

Comment: The jurisdiction is North America. Does the state matter?

Comment: employment laws are different in each state, so it would.

Comment: Your friend's manager is trading up from one lawsuit to two.

Comment: Get a tape recording.

Comment: @paparazzo: is it legal to record without consent?

Comment: @booleanbean depends on the state - some states have single party notification laws (only one party of the conversation needs to know it is being recorded), some require that all parties of the conversation need to be notified. New York (according to my googling) is a single-party notification state.

Comment: @booleanbean NY is a one party state.  So as long as one person is in on the conversation it is legal to record it without the other party knowing. Of course I am not a lawyer .. so consult a real one where needed.

Comment: What the manager is doing falls under the US Equal Opportunity definition of retaliation listed [here](https://www.eeoc.gov/laws/types/facts-retal.cfm). Definitely illegal.

Comment: This is big hairy deal huge.  This is obstruction of justice and if you follow through you could be jailed.  Your manager that told you this needs reported up the company chain, larger companies should have confidential reporting, but remember he could retaliate against you as well, and in right to work states you are vulnerable.  Wether your state allows two party consent or not I would secretly record all future conversations with your boss.  The only penalty having the recording is that it would not be admissible in court if not a two party state.

Comment: **Does your friend want to keep his job** after this? This is an important detail

Comment: Your fiend should approach a lawyer and explain the threat. Even if (s)he can't prove it, if the firing does happen, the fact that a lawyer was told about it beforehand will come in useful when suing that toxic company

Comment: @DanK How is this retaliation?  He's not retaliating against the person who was harassed, they already quit.  The person being threatened has done nothing to him, there's nothing to retaliate against.  This is just a case of applying a lot of pressure to do something wrong.

Comment: Here is a passage about recording conversations, including the list of states that are two-party consent states (11 two-party, 38 states and DC one-party, Hawaii one-party unless the recording device is hidden). http://www.dmlp.org/legal-guide/recording-phone-calls-and-conversations

Answer (score 24):

The optimum strategy is to go to HR and tell them: "Listen - this guy has sexual harassment charges against him. Now he wants me to convince the ex-employee to drop the charges. AND if I won't do that he's threatening to fire me. So not only will HE get two charges, one of which will be obstruction of justice, but THE COMPANY will get a third one for wrongful dismissal."

HR are there to protect the company and this "boss" is doing everything to make the company look bad. This is not good PR and if this case will make it look even *slightly* like the company is covering for the alleged sexual offence, the ship will hit the fan faster than the law team will be able to write a tweet with apologies.

Comment: But before doing that, get sound evidence like a recording or a email.

Comment: Do that in writing on an email. Print out that email after you send it and put it in a safety deposit box.

Comment: The company is already getting a sexual harassment charge--the wrongful dismissal would be the fourth, not the third.

Comment: This is dangerous.  The best bet is for the OP to get legal advise.

Comment: If you do this, get written proof of the boss's threats and your HR visit so when they fire you for "unrelated reasons" you can get unemployment.

Answer (score 18):

This is not the “boss” but the manager, so there’s probably someone above him. Your friend should talk to whoever is above the manager. And they also should talk to the co-workers lawyer who will be very interested. That action changes things from harassment which may or may not be proven to “perverting the course of justice”.

Reading comments, I’ll repeat that this is one manager, not the company. And telling someone about an attempt at perverting the course of justice (which in the U.K. carries a lengthy jail sentence) is your civic duty, not something any company can hold against you.

Comment: the "boss" is only in the title, for brevity; thanks for the point with _perverting the course of justice_ — this didn't occur to me.

Comment: Yes, talk to the boss's boss, or HR. This is one of the instances where HR would definitely be helpful.

Comment: Your friend should start documenting everyting - even writing in a notebook directly after a conversation is better than nothing.  However, try to do as much as possible over email, and he may want to consider bccing his personal address as well.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian Documenting everything is very important, however BCCing a private email address with company confidential information may be problematic (see [Bad Blood by John Carreyrou](https://www.penguinrandomhouse.com/books/549478/bad-blood-by-john-carreyrou/9781524731656/) for an example of using BCC to protect your self didn’t go well). I suggest its better to keep hard copies off site.

Comment: @BenMz I'm only suggesting bccing information related to the HR complaint or anything that could be used as part of a wrongful dismissal suit.  Could you explain why the book applies?  Also, something I noticed I disagree with in the answer - talking to the plaintiff's lawyer may work against the friend if that is discovered and he is fired for it.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian if the friend gets fired for talking to the lawyer, they will be able to file their own lawsuit and already be in contact with a lawyer who can handle the case.

Comment: @SethR He could make a wrongful dismissal claim, but while IANAL I think the employer would have a strong argument that giving information to opposing counsel without your company's consent or a court order in an active lawsuit against the company is a valid cause for dismissal.   At bare minimum I would advise the friend talk to his own counsel before making a decision.

Comment: Telling the truth about illegal things is not damaging the company. Doing illegal things is. If the company gets fined, for example, that’s the fault of the manager, not the fault of the informer.

Answer (score 7):

Your friend, whose manager implied directly or indirectly that they could lose their job if they don't participate in this activity, should **not** try to find an *"optimal solution."* Go to HR and upper management, report this. This is for your friend's protection, should this evolve into a harassment lawsuit - which it might, since @DanK brought up the US Equal Opportunity Employment laws related to retaliation.